# Send job results to sql table

Tags: sql

Ok a Newb question here:

I am trying to create a query as a job then log that query to a table.

```
SELECT login_name, total_elapsed_time, total_elapsed_time FROM     
sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

When I use INTO it creates a new table. I want to create a new record in an existing table Query_results.

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Based on the DMV in the question,its SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO SELECT` like this

```
INSERT INTO Query_results(login_name, total_elapsed_time, total_elapsed_time)
SELECT login_name, total_elapsed_time, total_elapsed_time FROM     
sys.dm_exec_sessions
```